# Point DNS label to specify port

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, azure

In Azure panel i can give a DNS label for my VM, but it doesn't point to 8080 as default.
To access website by dns i have to type
http://xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8080

I have specific 8080 endpoint in given path in azure portal.
All resources -> VM-Name -> Settings ->Inbound security rules -> 8080 rule
But i don't see any way to make it default.
[image: azure]

Whats steps are have to be made to make 8080 default port for DNS label?
VM runs on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly have a browser open port 8080 by default. Browsers open HTTP on port 80, and HTTPS, on port 443. DNS can't solve this problem directly because it's only responsible for translating xxx.cloudapp.westeurope.azure.com to your public IP.

3 possible solutions to the problem are as follow:

1) Change the server configuration on the server to listen on 80

2) Add a Web Server either on the Ubuntu host, or on a separate host to listen on 80 and redirect to port 80

3) You could add an azure load balancer and do a reverse NAT from 80 to 8080 on your server.

I strongly recommend against option 3 as it breaks many things from a scalability perspective later on, and isn't a very good fix.

Are you running a J2EE container listening on port 8080? It's been a while, but I think websphere listens to 8080 by default. If so best practice is to go with option 2. You shouldn't be serving directly off the container.

Answer (score 1):

DNS is used for name resolution - not the services behind this.

Check on the service definition or NAT to make your service accessible on application default ports (which is 80 for http / 443 for https)